# Writing to existing protected .xsml file in Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, vba

I am trying to use Openpyxl to write to an existing .xsml workbook, but it produces a workbook that Excel fails to open with macros still intact.

This workbook is also protected, so I believe it is therefore encrypted. I have tried setting keep_vba=true within openpyxl's load_workbook.

Is there any work around if openpyxl or other packages don't have this capability?